# How to select features that intersect but don't touch (using ArcObjects)?

Tags: arcobjects, features, intersection

So how do I do that? ArcMap's *Select By Location* selects also all features that touch, but I only need the ones that **actually** intersect the area.

I currently use `esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelIntersects` and there doesn't seem to be an option for what I need. `esriSpatialRelOverlaps` isn't an option because it doesn't cover the case when the geometries are excatly the same size and over each other. `esriSpatialRelCrosses` also doesn't work because it doesn't support Area/Area intersection.

So is this possible at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelRelation instead and set the [SpatialRelDescription](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/SpatialRelDescription_Property/00250000083w000000/) property to `pSFilter.SpatialRelDescription = "T***F****"`. This will only return the features that have the interiors intersecting.

Answer (score 1):

This probably should be a comment, instead of an answer, but I can't include images in comments.

The help page for [Using Select by Location](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s50000002q000000) says:

> A target feature will be selected if the intersection of its geometry
>   with the source feature is nonempty, but **the intersection of their
>   interiors is empty**. This is the definition of the Clementini touch
>   operator, so if the target feature touches (as defined by Clementini)
>   the source feature, it is selected.

But the image on the right (incorrectly?) shows that a polygon with an intersecting interior is selected - the middle yellow polygon is outlined with cyan, when it shouldn't be.

[image]